# FB.ui method 'auth.login' won't work

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It won't open anything.

```
function logIN()
{
    FB.ui({
        method: 'auth.login',
        perms: 'email',
        display: 'iframe' },
        function(response) {
            /* */
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should be your function instead:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'oauth',
  display: 'popup',
  scope: 'email',
  response_type: 'token',
  redirect_uri: 'WHEREYOUWANTTOPROCESSTOKEN',
  client_id: 'YOURAPPID',
});
```

Note that only `page` or `popup` are valid types for `display`

Comment: (-1) display must be one of :
1- popup 2- dialog 3- iframe 4- touch 5- async 5- hidden 6-none

Comment: Those parameters can be used with other dialogs, but I believe that Auth dialogs specifically only allow page and popup to secure this important stage of the authentication process. Touch may also be valid here too, but it's probably not useful for anything other than mobile.

Comment: this is the response from the server if you use page display :)

Comment: `scope: 'email'` doesn't work for me, but `perms: 'email'` seems to work. Also redirect_uri doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This example might help: http://fbrell.com/auth/login-and-logout

```
<button id="fb-auth">Login</button>

<script>
function updateButton(response) {
  console.log('Updating Button', response);
  var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

  if (response.session) {
    button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
    button.onclick = function() {
      FB.logout(function(response) {
        console.log('FB.logout callback', response);
      });
    };
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = 'Login';
    button.onclick = function() {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        console.log('FB.login callback', response);
        if (response.session) {
          console.log('User is logged in');
        } else {
          console.log('User is logged out');
        }
      });
    };
  }
}

// run it once with the current status and also whenever the status changes
FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
</script>
```